# Question about retreiving specific process runinng files VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, process, vb.net-2010, c#-to-vb.net

I would like to be able to list all files that are currently open by process for example "EXCEL" so I can get the files paths.

I am using the following code which retrieve only the first file opened and the for each loop ends:

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessRuningName)
    Try
        Using searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " & p.Id)
            For Each mgmtObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                cl = mgmtObj.Item("CommandLine").ToString().Split("""")
                For x = 0 To cl.Count - 1
                    Dim FilePath As String = cl(x)
                    If System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath) = FileName Then
                        processFilesRuning.Add(FileName)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End Using
    Catch ex As Win32Exception
        'handle error
    End Try
Next
```

So as you can see I'm trying to search in each process with the name of "Excel" which is already retrieved but I get only one result which is the first opened Excel file and it ignores the other opened file.

Comment: Questions: Variable ```FileName``` isn't instantiated or populated in this sub, so presumably it happens earlier.  However it's what you add to `processFilesRuning` when a match is found.  Do you really want to add `FileName` rather than the full path of the match found in the enumeration?  It seems as though you'll keep adding the exact same thing multiple times, and though the filename may match their paths could be different, but you aren't capturing that.  Also have you checked the `count` property of the match collection `cl`?

Comment: Hey technonaut31337,
FileName is a variable that im getting the file name that is already opened because files are opened through the app it self so im having a list of the (process Name And the file name (path isnt important because the files are in the same of app location) ) When i add FileName to processFilesRuning is to know that this file is still runing and at the end of the Sub im clearing the list because its a timer and every time it can build the list again and the count is to get the filename/Location because different file types give different results for example, Next Reply

Comment: ( Notepad cl(2) and excel cl(3) ) so i need a loop that checks the file in each entry in cl() and its working really good but the problem that the main loop ( For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessRuningName) ) ends with the first file so if there is more than one file opened it will retreive only the first file.